# Google chart's date issue

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am getting a utc date string in json response which i am converting to locale date object but when i am passing this date to google charts as a date i get 
"Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string" error

This is my js code

```
var localDate = new Date();
                var localTimeZoneOffset = localDate.getTimezoneOffset();
                var longDateValue = Date.parse(element.dateAndTime);
                var date = new Date(longDateValue);
                alert(date);
                //var dateTime = calculateLocaleDate(element.dateAndTime);
                var jobId = element.jobId;
                var userId = element.userId;
                var status = element.status;
                var jobType = element.jobType;
                data.addRow([date, jobId, userId, status, jobType]);
```

And this is my table declaration

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'Date & Time');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Job Id');
        data.addColumn('string', 'User Id');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Status');
        data.addColumn('string', 'JobType');
        var cssClassNames = {
            'headerCell': 'table-th-td'
        };
```

Actually i want to create adate range filter like this on date data

```
var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'control1',
        'options': {
               // Filter by the date axis.
            //'filterColumnIndex': 0,
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Date & Time',
            'ui': {
             'chartType': 'LineChart',
             'chartOptions': {
             'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
             'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'}
                  },
            // Display a single series that shows the closing value of the stock.
            // Thus, this view has two columns: the date (axis) and the stock value (line series).
            'chartView': {
            'columns': [0, 3]
                },
            // 1 day in milliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 86,400,000
           'minRangeSize': 86400000
            }
            },
        // Initial range: 2012-02-09 to 2012-03-20.
        'state': {'range': {'start': new Date(2013, 11, 15), 'end': new Date(2013, 11, 20)}}
        });
```

I am not sure where is the problem, is it in the table declaration, filter decalaration or in the row creation

Comment: Which package do you have loaded? `corechart` or `LineChart`? With `corechart` package I got the same message but with `LineChart` not.

Comment: The `LineChart` package is deprecated - don't use it.  Can you post an example of `element.dateAndTime`?

Comment: _asgallant_ is right. I don't know why I used that package.